# Accessibility: Talkback for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, accessibility

**Scenario**

I am creating one application that has bottom navigation. For 1 bottom navigation item, I have a Fragment with a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`

Let say I have 3 bottom navigation item A, B and C

For C we have fragment FragmentC. And in FragmentC there are again 3 TabItem, X, Y and Z.

With default implementation, when talkback reads any of tab(X, Y OR Z), it says "X tab, 1 of 3"

**Requirement**

I want tab X, Y and Z to be read differently as

"X in C, tab 1 of 3"

**Code**

This is what I did

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewPager.adapter?.let { adapter ->
            for (i in 0..adapter.count) {
                tabs.getTabAt(i)
                    ?.let {
                        it.contentDescription = setAccessibilityForTabs(i, adapter.count)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setAccessibilityForTabs(pos: Int, size: Int) = when (pos) {
        0 -> "X in C, tab 1 of 3"
        1 -> "Y in X, tab 2 of 3"
        else -> "Z in X, tab 3 of 3"
    }
```

After this, talkback read it as
"X in C, tab 1 of 3, tab X 1 of 3"

So I changed above method as

```
    private fun setAccessibilityForTabs(pos: Int, size: Int) = when (pos) {
        0 -> "X in C"
        1 -> "Y in X"
        else -> "Z in X"
    }
```

Now, outcome of this is
"X in C, tab X 1 of 3"

Is there any way I can make this read as "X in C, tab 1 of 3" ?

Comment: Look like some view adds additional text to ContentDescription like in TabView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo() method. You can try to check view with recursively to find content description with text "tab X 1 of 3" . Then set for this view content description as null or use `importantForAccessibility` = `no`

Comment: @ArtemViter I check and found that the announcement is a mix of 2 views. 1 is Tab title which is in Tab.view and other is tab count which is in Tab.parent(Both probably getting removed in future as per the comment on those variables). Still let me try your approach

Comment: @ArtemViter I tried setting `importantForAccessibility` to NO for all other child views and parent but somehow that "Tab X" is getting added

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what else to do...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar but after a lot of changes, the following works for me.

For some reason the tab's text is appending to the content description. I was trying to follow when it is happening but I couldn't located. I only found that if the contentDescription was not added and we set its text. The text is added automatically as contentDescription. [Reference](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/359580b6c1160301967ebdededb1011c1133b42c/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.java#L2347)

So my current code was something like this

```
val tab = tabLayout.newTab()
tab.text = "TITLE"
tab.tag = SOMETHING
....
....
tab.contentDescription = "My content description"
```

I updated this code to the following

```
val tab = tabLayout.newTab()
tab.contentDescription = "My content description"
tab.tag = SOMETHING
....
....
tab.text = "My title"
```

Basically, changing the order of the setup. Set the tab's text as the last step.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rguzman answer, I had to force tooltipText too in tab view :

```
val tab = tabLayout.newTab()
tab.contentDescription = "My content description"
tab.text = "My title"
tab.view.tooltipText = "My content description"
```